# How to reference constructed variables from a dynamically added function

Tags: php, class

How would one rewrite the following ...

```php
class crunch {

    private $funcs = [];

    public function set($name, $function) {
        $this->funcs[$name] = $function;
    }

    public function call($function, $data=false) {
        if (isset($this->funcs[$function]) && is_callable($this->funcs[$function])) {
            return $this->funcs[$function]($data);
        }
    }
}

$db = 'dbhandle';

$crunch = new crunch();

$crunch->set('myfunction', function($data) {
    global $db;
    echo 'db = '. $db .'<br>'. json_encode( $data );
});

$crunch->call('myfunction', [123,'asd']);
```

... which correctly outputs ...

```
db = dbhandle
[123,"asd"]
```

... to remove the ugly `global` requirement when using frequently used variables/handles within dynamically added functions?

Normally, I'd define the global on construction as follows, but this understandably fails with the fatal error `Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context` ...

```php
class crunch {

    private $db;
    private $funcs = [];

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function set($name, $function) {
        $this->funcs[$name] = $function;
    }

    public function call($function, $data=false) {
        if (isset($this->funcs[$function]) && is_callable($this->funcs[$function])) {
            return $this->funcs[$function]($data);
        }
    }
}

$db = 'dbhandle';

$crunch = new crunch($db);

$crunch->set('myfunction', function($data) {
    echo 'db = '. $this->db .'<br>'. json_encode( $data );
});

$crunch->call('myfunction', [123,'asd']);
```

What's the cleanest way to accomplish the goal?

**EDIT**: As @Rajdeep points out, I could pass $db within the `$crunch->set()` function. But I'd like to avoid this, since each dynamic function could reference anywhere from 0-5 of these private variables, and it would be inelegant to have to call all 5 with every `$crunch->set()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a private instance variable `$db`, you could simply pass this variable to the `call()` method. Your code should be like this:

```
class crunch {

    private $funcs = [];

    public function set($name, $function) {
        $this->funcs[$name] = $function;
    }

    public function call($function, $data=false, $db) {
        if (isset($this->funcs[$function]) && is_callable($this->funcs[$function])) {
            return $this->funcs[$function]($data, $db);
        }
    }
}

$db = 'dbhandle';

$crunch = new crunch();

$crunch->set('myfunction', function($data, $db){
    echo 'db = '. $db .'<br>'. json_encode( $data );
});

$crunch->call('myfunction', [123,'asd'], $db);
```

**Output:**

```
db = dbhandle
[123,"asd"]
```

## Update(1):

In case you want to access `$db` as instance variable only, **the solution** would be like this:

```
class crunch {

    public $db;
    private $funcs = [];

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function set($name, $function) {
        $this->funcs[$name] = $function;
    }

    public function call($function, $data=false) {
        if (isset($this->funcs[$function]) && is_callable($this->funcs[$function])) {
            return $this->funcs[$function]($this, $data);
        }
    }
}

$db = 'dbhandle';

$crunch = new crunch($db);

$crunch->set('myfunction', function($crunch, $data) {
    echo 'db = '. $crunch->db .'<br>'. json_encode( $data );
});

$crunch->call('myfunction', [123,'asd']);
```

**Note that** you have to make `$db` as public member variable, otherwise it would be inaccessible while calling the `set()` method.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. What I should have mentioned is that each added function could reference anywhere from 0 to 5 of these private instance variables ... and that part of what I'd like to avoid is having to include all 5 each time I call `$crunch->set()`. I'll edit my question now to clarify this.

Comment: @neokio So you want to access `$db` through private instance variable only, right?

Comment: Yes, if possible, I'd like to have $db and a half-dozen more variables/handles be added **on construction**, yet still available to dynamically added functions. Some added functions will not require any of these private instance variables, others will use all of them.

Comment: @neokio I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer.

Comment: Wow! That's a totally excellent and mind-bending solution. Impressive, thank you!